# How did using gcc -O2 optimization resolved issue: pointer pointing nothing and having integer value as -23 in it, is gone?

Tags: c, gcc, memory-management

I had a piece of code in my project which was giving me some issue.

```
char* reverseString (char* str){
    char* outputString = NULL; 
    /* Calculate length of the string */
    int len = strlen(str);
    outputString = (char *)malloc(len*(sizeof(char)));   
    int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int x = 5;
    *p = 25;
    free(p);
    return outputString;
}
```

IN following test cases:

```
input char input1[]="a";     
char input2[]="";
```

called with both the inputs

```
char* res = reverseString(input1);
char* res2 = reverseString(input2);
```

I executed the following code in the project:

```
char str2[] = "a";
char* res = reverseString(str2);
if (strlen(res2)==0 || res==NULL)
    printf("hello");
printf("%s",res);       // No output came out
char str3[] = "";
char* res2 = reverseString(str3);
if (strlen(res2)==0 || !*res2)
    printf("hello");
printf("%s",res2);

free(res);
free(res2);
```

There was no output at all
res and res2 was pointing to nothing not even NULL.
Also this code works if input string's length is larger than 2
problem that I was facing is outputString was nothing, literally nothing.
I tried comparisons with  NULL/(void*) every possible combination I could think off:

```
(str[0]=='\0' || str[0]=='0' || !str[0] || str[0]==(char)0 || *str ==   (char)0 ||(!*str) ||strlen(str)==0 )
```

its strlen(outputString) was coming out to be 1

I also saw the address of outputString didn't change before and after calling free(p)
If I commented out free(p) then everything was working fine,

Then I separated that code into a small program but problem didn't reproduce.

I did

```
printf("%c %d",outputString[0], outputString[0]-'0');
```

No character printed only an integer -23 printed out.

Then I compiled the code with gcc -O2 
then suddenly problem got resolved.

Also other thing resolved my issue 
free the memory before next function call.
Like the following:

```
char str2[] = "a";
char* res = reverseString(str);
if (strlen(res)==0 || res==NULL)
    printf("hello");     // This gave the output hello
printf("%s",res);   
free(res);
char str3[] = "";
char* res2 = reverseString(str3);
if (strlen(res)==0 || !*res2)
    printf("hello");       // This gave the output hello
printf("%s",res2);
```

free(res3);

This worked fine.

I tried alot to understand whats going wrong.
Can somebody tell me what is the problem and what is going wrong and how did use of optimization resolved it.
why can't I free the memory all at once in the end. As I still have pointer to the memory which was allocated within that function call.

Also to debug this issue I wrote an  MCVE but it didn't reproduce the issue. Only within the project it happened. 
Hence there is no point of providing MCVE

IN MCVE comparison to NULL was working but surprisingly not in my project

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* reverseString (char* str){
char* outputString = NULL;
/* Calculate lenght of the string */
int len = strlen(str);
/* allocate memory of size equal to the length of the given string */
outputString = (char *)calloc(len*(sizeof(char)),0);

 int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
 int x = 5;
 *p = 25;
 free(p);
 return outputString;
}
int main()
{

char str2[] = "a";
char* res2 = reverseString(str2);
if (strlen(res2)==0 || res2==NULL)
    printf("hello");
printf("%s",res2);   // No output as expected.
char str3[] = "";
char* res3 = reverseString(str3);
if (strlen(res3)==0 || !*res3)
    printf("hello");
printf("%s",res3);

free(res2);
free(res3);
}
```

Also I modified my code such that at the end of function call I free outputString:
   free(res)
and then made the next call free(res2);

Comment: Because of UB. "_There was no output at all res and res2 was pointing to nothing not even NULL_" -- `res` and `res2` points to the start allocated memory segment. **This memory segment contains garbage as you've not copied any thing to it**.

Comment: How did adding -O2 optimization option in gcc resolved this issue? M trying to understand the benefit of optimization. Should I consider it using for my project.

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy some data to the output buffer! Right now the contents could be anything.

Also, you need to allocate space for string terminator.

So:

```
outputString = malloc(len + 1);  // +1 to fit string terminator
```

And add:

```
for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
    outputString[i] = str[len - i - 1];
} 
outputString[len] = '\0';
```

The reason your MCVE doesn't reproduce the problem is because it is using `calloc`, so the allocated buffer is filled with 0.

Comment: `strcpy` is easier if you just want to put some data in the string. However, I just couldn't let a function called `reverseString` do a plain `strcpy`.

Comment: Ah. Missed the `reverseString`... :-)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was trying too many things. the problem started with malloc, at one point I changed to calloc for testing and forgot to replace it back. Also I tried calloc in my project but the problem didn't go away.M curious how did the problem go away by using -O2 optimization option with gcc.

Comment: I tried malloc in MSVE as well but issue didn't reproduce.

Comment: The problem didn't go away. You were still using uninitialized memory. There just happened to be other values in the memory block you got.